# Python 2.7 BeautifulSoup returning incorrect meta tag values

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying the below script using Requests and BeautifulSoup to get the first meta tag with the property of 'og:image'.

The returned value should be:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://images.metadata.sky.com/pd-image/ad81add2-dff2-4c4d-8596-277bb22c0905/16-9">
```

...however, I keep getting:

```
<meta content="https://dm8eklel4s62k.cloudfront.net/images/sky-logo-b90e8c9.jpg" property="og:image"/>
```

The link `https://dm8eklel4s62k.cloudfront.net/images/sky-logo-b90e8c9.jpg` is actually in the source code for the page in question, but within the Javascript respinse and not the page header metadata values. Curiously, if you change `find` to `findAll`, all the other meta tags are correct except for this one.

Any ideas?

```
import requests
import beautiful soup


session = requests.Session()
jar = session.cookies
url ='https://www.sky.com/new-search/air-crash-investigation/?q=air%20crash%20investigation'

headers = {
'authority': 'www.sky.com',
'method': 'GET',
'path': url_split,
'scheme': 'https',
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'
}

params = {
'q': url_string2
}

r = session.get(url, headers=headers, params=params, cookies=jar)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

prop = soup.find('meta', attrs={'property': 'og:image'})
print prop
```

Comment: Your first step should be switching to Python 3! 2 only has a month or so left...

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's the correct result. it’s returning what you want, just in a different order. You are just have different output due that you are blocked by `CloudFront`

Check the link which in your expected output and check mine. it's the same.

Yours is different due to block by `CloudFront`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    'https://www.sky.com/new-search/air-crash-investigation/?q=air%20crash%20investigation')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('meta', attrs={'property': 'og:image'}):
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
<meta content="https://images.metadata.sky.com/pd-image/ad81add2-dff2-4c4d-8596-277bb22c0905/16-9" property="og:image"/>
```